# Modify "plans shown on the battery meter"

Tags: windows-8, power-management

I always use Power Saver or High Performance.  No in between for me.  How can I rearrange the plans so that those are the two in the top section?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an app to get around this.  It's called [Power Buddy](https://github.com/MetaFight/PowerBuddy/releases).

Comment: The icon could use some love, but it's simple and does what it says!  Nice work.

Comment: yeah, the icon is pretty bad :), but it hasn't annoyed me enough yet to fix it.  If the app gets a small following I might put some time in to fix it .

Comment: If you changed the Icon to be a Battery meter, it would be a great replacement for the original battery icon. Thanks @MetaFight for the app, it's a great little util!

Answer (score 4):

You CAN'T do that in Windows 7 and Windows 8. You can say that Microsoft messed it up after Windows Vista.
The 'Balanced' plan is always fixed in the battery meter pop up followed by the plan you most recently used.

Windows 7 and Windows 8:

[image]

This was possible only on Windows Vista :

[image]

A workaround is that you can change the plan settings of 'Balanced' to work like 'High Performance' and have the 'Power Saver' as the most recently used power plan.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on my laptop. You could just edit the balanced config and make it so it is set up to be the same as high performance. This way it is still called balanced but acts the same as high performance would. Or you can use a program like [Power Plan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/home.htm) which enables all sorts of useful battery and power related shortcuts and statuses.

Comment: I can't get to that website.  Not sure if it's a DNS problem at this coffee shop or what.  I'll check it out later.

Comment: PPA Broken link.